# mysql - JOIN or UNION - not sure which, maybe both

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to combine data from two files but I am having trouble expressing the sort. I want to sort on either the CREATED date from the first file and the SHARED_DATE from the second file if it exists and it is larger.

```
    file 1 : NODE# 
    fields: CREATED, CHANGED

    file 2 : SHARE_CONTENT   
    fields:  SHARED_DATE ,  NODE# (foreign key)


select * from NODE as n left join SHARE_CONTENT as s on (s.NODE#=n.NODE#)
ORDER BY [higher of n.CREATED  and s.SHARED_DATE]
```

Answer (score 1):

sorted by LastDate

```
SELECT n.*,s.*,
(CASE WHEN n.CREATED > s.SHARED_DATE then n.CREATED else s.SHARED_DATE end) as LastDate
FROM node as n LEFT JOIN share_conten as s on (s.NODE#=n.NODE#)
ORDER BY LastDate DESC
```

Comment: Does this correctly handle the case where `s` doesn't exist?  It seems to me that it wouldn't, because `n.created > s.shared_date` would NOT evaluate to true.

Comment: You are right... but there was a [part II](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8950110/1158170) which handles this problem

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the part 2, because I found this question under the "sql" tag, which is missing from part 2.  I wonder why the OP just didn't edit the original question.  I think I'll go and post my own answer to part 2; in case Mustapha George ever needs names for more than one child :-)

Answer (score 0):

My SQL skills are a bit rusty, but it appears you want to combine the two tables in one query, showing all of the information together while matching the returned rows? I think this is a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Here is a great visual reference of [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

And you can use ORDER BY MAX(n.CREATED, s.SHARED_DATE); NULLS that get introduced by a FULL OUTER JOIN will get ignored by MAX (that is, the MAX of anything and NULL is that thing).

Comment: looks promising but mySQL 4.1 does not seem to like ORDER BY(CAL1, VAL2)