# mysql - JOIN or UNION - not sure which, maybe both (part II)

Tags: mysql, left-join

*** revised, but still not solved...*

I want to combine data from two files but I am having trouble expressing the sort. I want to sort on either the CREATED date from the first file and the SHARED_DATE from the second file if it exists and it is larger.

```
file 1 : NODE 
fields: CREATED, CHANGED

file 2 : SHARE_CONTENT   
fields:  SHARED_DATE ,  NODE (foreign key)
```

...

```
SELECT n.created, s.shared_date,

(CASE WHEN s.shared_date <> NULL
   then  s.shared_date
   else n.created
END) 
as lastshare

FROM node as n LEFT JOIN share_content as s on (s.nid=n.nid)

ORDER BY lastshare DESC
```

---

another possibility..

```
SELECT n.created, s.shared_date,
FROM node as n LEFT JOIN share_content as s on (s.nid=n.nid)
ORDER BY MAX(n.created, s.shared_date) DESC
```

except mySQL does not seem to like MAX(a,b)

Comment: `MAX(..)` only work with `Group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT n.created, s.shared_date,
(CASE WHEN (s.shared_date IS NOT NULL) And (s.Shared_Date > n.Created)
   then  s.shared_date
   else n.created
END) 
as lastshare
FROM node as n LEFT JOIN share_content as s on (s.nid=n.nid)
ORDER BY lastshare DESC
```

Specifically note the IS NOT instead of <>. NULL is very, very special in SQL.

Comment: Only if it's a boy, please. If I meet a little girl called Stu in a few years, I'll be very, very miffed!

Comment: We'll call her Sue!   (that's a cheap Johnny Cash joke http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1BJfDvSITY)

Comment: You, sir, win one Internets for the evening.

Comment: The `(s.shared_date IS NOT NULL) And` is redundant.  The `(S.shared_Date > n.Created )` will evaluate to false if `s.Shared_Date` is null.  So the answer would be a little shorter if you omitted this clause.  I was going to post that as a separate answer, but didn't want to run the risk of running into a little girl called David :-).

Comment: Very true... I always make such NULL assumptions explicit to make sure those that come after me know what was intended. I should've said so.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.created, s.shared_date,

(CASE WHEN s.shared_date IS NOT NULL
   THEN 
       (CASE WHEN s.shared_date > n.created 
       THEN s.shared_date ELSE n.created END)
   ELSE n.created
END) 
as lastshare

FROM node as n LEFT JOIN share_content as s on (s.nid=n.nid)

ORDER BY lastshare DESC
```

Now it should work like you want ;)